# Create several group based on their Interest-based

Tags: php, mysql, rows

Create several group based on their Interest-based. I am using php and mysql.

my user table

1. name_one
2. name_two
3. name_three
4. name_four
5. etc..
   6.
   7.
   8.

I would to select some names and create a group

Ex:

256 users interest in football = Foot Ball group

549 users interest in cricket = Cricket Group

Note: Football users can be in cricket as well.

My question is how can I create many users group from user table rows. Should it create extra table? Please help me.

Comment: You could create a Group table and another table to keep the relation between user and goup since it's a many to many relation..

Comment: This is starting with databases 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create a table `interest(id_interest, name)`, then a 3rd table `interest_user(id_user, id_interest)`

I suggest using `interest` as table name instead of `group` because it has a special meaning in mysql.

Comment: Thanks, It's simple and i love it.